# Issue with the detail pane in a window

Tags: gui, interface, 16.10

I've got an issue with the detail section of almost all windows under Ubuntu 16.10; it shows this:
[image: Screenshot]

and doesn't expand correctly and won't show all the items in the list.

*Can anyone tell me how to fix this?*

Comment: Same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861573/details-panel-minimised). Did you get any solution?

Comment: sadly i dont, i change to another distro of linux, and it worked well untill an update comes out and it start to display the same so

Comment: sadly i don't, i change to another distro of linux, and it worked well until an update comes out and it start to display the same so I just let it go. @KhurramRaza